# .classpath file does not exist in new projects

Tags: java, android, eclipse, vim, eclim

I'm just starting out android development with eclim, and I'm getting somewhat frustrated just trying to get a hello world going. While inside my workspace, I enter vim, type `:ProjectCreate /$PATH_TO_MY_PERSONAL_PROJECT -n android`. I'm walked through the steps, but when I enter the project root directory, no `.classpath` file exists. The `.project` file is there, and the directory is created, but eclim doesn't report any existing projects when I execute `:ProjectList` in vim.

Are there special steps I must go through to get eclim to recognize the android SDK?
Any ideas what's going on here?

Using eclim 1.7.14 and android API 17.

Thank so much in advance!

Comment: I think .classpath is a file of the IDE eclipse.

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you create your project from Eclipse itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this seems to be a problem associated with Eclim alone, not eclipse. The easiest solution for those of us who want to keep our business inside the terminal is to use the android tools provided instead of using eclim to create projects from inside of vim. Just enter the command:

`android create project --fill in project specs in options`

to create projects from scratch with no problems.